# "I would like to be sent something" "Could I be sent something"

Tags: grammaticality, register, social-interaction

Are these sentences grammatically correct?

- I would like to be sent some information on your hotel facilities.
- Could I please be sent some information on your hotel facilities?

Which of these is a better option?

Comment: Hi, proof reading questions are not on topic here. You might want to take this to ELL.

Answer (score 1):

Both the sentences are grammatically correct but in the context that you've provided, it's better check the tone and the voice and modify them accordingly.

Passive: Could I please be sent some information on your hotel facilities?

Active: Could you please send me some information on your hotel facilities?(more polite)

Passive: I would like to be sent some information on your hotel facilities.

Active: I would like you to send me some information on your hotel facilities.(less polite, slightly commanding)

Comment: I agree with the recommendation to use active voice.  To soften the request: I would like to ask you to send...; I would appreciate it if you could send...; I hope it would not be too much trouble to ask you to send....

Comment: Thank you for your comments and suggestions, Aishwarya. Your answer tells me that the passive "someone to be sent something" is grammactically correct. Is it good English either? Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, it is correct but it has a commanding tone: _This work needs to be done_, _He needs to be sent that message_ etc are grammatically correct. It is definitely good English, but it's more common to say "I need to send him that message"